# Lifecycles callbacks seems to be not invoked on persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Inside entity class:

```
/** @Entity @HasLifecycleCallbacks */ 
 class Job {

    /** @PrePersist */    
    public function setCreatedAtOnCreate()
    {
      //some code
    }

    /** @PrePersist */
    public function setExpiresAtOnCreate()
    { 
      //some code
    }
```

Updating database data with command doctrine:fixtures:load gives me an error:

> Column created_at cannot be null.

Could somebody help? What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After defining you callback function,you must specify these 2 function as parameters of lifecycleCallbacks: in yaml file of corresponding entity. If you are using XML specify there.
Below is an example how lifecycle call back works using yaml.

```
class myentity{

private $createdAt ;
private $updatedAt ;
public function setCreatedAtValue()
    {
      $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function setUpdatedAtValue()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

In your Yaml file correspoding to this entity, you must invoke this 2 functions in lifecycle callback,

```
Myproject\MytBundle\Entity\myentity:
  type: entity
  table: myentity
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue,setUpdatedAtValue ]
    preUpdate: [ setUpdatedAtValue ]
```

This call back will call before inserting data into the DB and setUpdatedAtValue function will call before updating any value in Db

Hopefully this will help you.
Happy coding.

Comment: I am having same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992549/symfony2-orm-prepersist-not-working  Can you please suggest?

Comment: Hello Neeraj @ in yaml file intentation is very important so I think defenitly this was ur probs

Comment: So what i am missing in the Entity File? Did you saw that post i mentioned above?

Comment: I am using Annotations.